# how to change movieclip as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

i want to change 2 movieclip on 1 frame, first movieclip is for intro when app is started, and the second movieclip is continue of first.
here my code :

```
var sunR1:classSunRays1; //movieclip export
var sunR2:classSunRays2; //movieclip export   

function intro():void{

            sunR1 = new clsSunRays1();
            sunR1.x = mapW/2;
            sunR1.y = mapH/2;
            sunR1.width += 200;
            sunR1.height += 200;
            stage.addChild(sunR1);
            if (sunR1.currentFrame == sunR1.totalFrames){
                stage.removeChild(sunR1);
                sunR2 = new clsSunRays2();
                sunR2.x = mapW/2;
                sunR2.y = mapH/2;
                sunR1.width += 200;
                sunR1.height += 200;
                stage.addChild(sunR2);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
function intro():void
{
   sunR1 = new classSunRays1();
   sunR1.stop();
   sunR1.x = mapW/2;
   sunR1.y = mapH/2;
   sunR1.width += 200;
   sunR1.height += 200;
   stage.addChild(sunR1);
   // adding a function to be called in the last frame (when you will apply your logic)
   sunR1.addFrameScript(sunR1.totalFrames -1, changeMovieClip);
   sunR1.play();
}

function changeMovieClip():void
{
    sunR1.stop();
    stage.removeChild(sunR1);
    sunR2 = new classSunRays2();
    sunR2.stop();
    sunR2.x = mapW/2;
    sunR2.y = mapH/2;
    sunR2.width += 200;
    sunR2.height += 200;
    stage.addChild(sunR2);
    sunR2.play();
}
```